# Syntax highlighting on the server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I have blocks of code that I want to highlight.I'm currently using prismjs. The thing is, I'm highlighting multiple blocks of code and the page takes more than 5 seconds to load on my not-so-slow PC.

If I take the prism code highlight, the loading is close to instant. So I'm assuming the issue is highlighting the code.

How do I render the code highlights on the server (server-side-rendering)?

I'm using nextjs 9.5.* in a react app. I have no issue changing to another highlighting library.

Answer (score 1):

While your question is 6 months old and I guess you've figured out since, I can give a recommendation for [prism-react-renderer](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/prism-react-renderer) created by [Formidable labs](https://github.com/FormidableLabs). I am not sure about performance benefits *per se* (it is built atop PrismJS), but it supports SSR and SSG (which is, due to my experience, problematic, using bare PrismJS).

Comment: I went with rehype-highlight. I made it work with both browser and server, you can see the example in this PR: https://github.com/rehypejs/rehype-highlight/pull/14

Comment: Thanks for a tip, `rehype-highlight` looks quite interesting (although a little heavy, when checking with bundlephobia; but I guess that is the point of your PR).

Comment: it's around 100kB for JavaScript and TypeScript (the common bundle at the time was around 90kB I think). How big is the bundle with prism? And how many languages are you using?

Comment: Bundlephobia shows 274 Kb for `rehype-highlight`, 22 Kb for `prism-react-renderer` and 6.5 Kb for bare `Prismjs`. But it is probably not the right measure, because **a)** it is highly dependent on how each library imports language modules (I think `PrismJS` doesn't require any by default, that's why it's so tiny) **b)** considering SSR or SSG, it wouldn't matter much, because the library doesn't have to be included in the clients bundle (at least until re-hydration).

Comment: rehype-highlight doesn't require any language by default either. For a closer comparison you could probably check rehype-prism https://github.com/mapbox/rehype-prism. The nice thing about rehype/unifiedjs stuff is that you can chain transformations for the markdown.